# How to check if concrete type of cache is enabled in M1?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

For example how to check if "Blocks HTML output" is enabled, strangely I have trouble to find out that information.

I'd like to know that in order to add conditions before saving and loading custom cached content which is **parts** of the HTML block output and is programmed in the template file because in the inner HTML I had to output dynamic data a couple times, so I am doing custom "hole punching" and the block class is not caching the whole template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how you get all Cache types with the status

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes()
```

If you take a look in `Mage_Core_Model_Cache` you can see the Method `canUse()` The Description of the Method is:

> Check if cache can be used for specific data type

I think it's exactly what you need and the return is true or false. You can call it like this:

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->canUse('block_html')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking exact at that code before asking, not sure why I decided it is something else. I would just add that instead of using hard-coded block type ID, I use `$this::CACHE_GROUP`, where `$this` is in a template file of a block. So the code becomes:
`Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->canUse($this::CACHE_GROUP)`